# "Incorrect number of bindings supplied" cPython 3.5 SQLite3 VS15

Tags: python, csv, sqlite, insert

```
import csv
import sqlite3

fileName = 'australianpublicholidays.csv'
accessMode = 'r'

# Create a database in RAM
holidayDatabase = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

# Create a cursor
c = holidayDatabase.cursor()

# Create a table
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE holidays 
(date text, holidayName text, information text, moreInformation text, applicableTo text)''')

# Read the file contents in to the table
with open(fileName, accessMode) as publicHolidays :
    listOfPublicHolidays = csv.reader(publicHolidays)

    for currentRow in listOfPublicHolidays :
        for currentEntry in currentRow :
            c.execute('INSERT INTO holidays VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', currentEntry)

# Close the database
holidayDatabase.close()
```

The following line

```
    c.execute('INSERT INTO holidays VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', currentEntry)
```

is causing this error

> Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 5,
>   and there are 4 supplied.

Comment: What do the contents of currentEntry look like?

Comment: [https://imgur.com/VEn8i0k](https://imgur.com/VEn8i0k)

Running in a virtual machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currentRow` is already a sequence.  It's a list of all of the fields in the row.
If you were to print out `currentRow`, you'd get output like this *(assuming this is your data set https://data.gov.au/dataset/australian-holidays-machine-readable-dataset)*:

```
['Date', 'Holiday Name', 'Information', 'More Information', 'Applicable To']
['20150101', "New Year's Day", "New Year's Day is the first day of the calendaryear and is celebrated each January 1st", '', 'NAT']
['20150126', 'Australia Day', 'Always celebrated on 26 January', 'http://www.australiaday.org.au/', 'NAT']
['20150302', 'Labour Day', 'Always on a Monday, creating a long weekend. It celebrates the eight-hour working day, a victory for workers in the mid-late 19th century.',http://www.commerce.wa.gov.au/labour-relations/public-holidays-western-australia', 'WA']
...
```

When you do

```
for currentEntry in currentRow :
    c.execute('INSERT INTO holidays VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', currentEntry)
```

You're actually getting a list of all of the characters in the first element in the list.
Because you didn't skip the header row, you're actually getting a list of the characters in the word **"Date"**.  Which equals 4 characters and is causing the error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current sta
tement uses 5, and there are 4 supplied.
```

If you were to skip the header line using `next(listOfPublicHolidays, None)` as in:

```
with open(fileName, accessMode) as publicHolidays :
    listOfPublicHolidays = csv.reader(publicHolidays)
    next(listOfPublicHolidays, None)
    for currentRow in listOfPublicHolidays :
        for currentEntry in currentRow :
        c.execute('INSERT INTO holidays VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', currentEntry)
```

you would get the following error message because `currentEntry` would be a list of the characters in **"20150101"**, having a length of 8:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "holidaysorig.py", line 25, in <module>
    c.execute('INSERT INTO holidays VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', tuple(currentEntry)
)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 5, and there are 8 supplied.
```

That's why it works (for the most part) when you remove the `for currentEntry in currentRow :` block and rewrite it as:

```
import csv
import sqlite3

fileName = 'australianpublicholidays.csv'
accessMode = 'r'

# Create a database in RAM
holidayDatabase = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

# Create a cursor
c = holidayDatabase.cursor()

# Create a table
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE holidays 
(date text, holidayName text, information text, moreInformation text, applicableTo text)''')

# Read the file contents in to the table
with open(fileName, accessMode) as publicHolidays :
    listOfPublicHolidays = csv.reader(publicHolidays)
    for currentRow in listOfPublicHolidays :
        c.execute('INSERT INTO holidays VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', currentRow)

# Close the database
holidayDatabase.close()
```

**NOTE:** On my machine, I got the following errors:

```
(holidays) C:\Users\eyounjo\projects\holidays>python holidaysorig.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "holidaysorig.py", line 22, in <module>
    c.execute('INSERT INTO holidays VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', currentRow)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

So I rewrote your script as the following to deal with the above:

```
import csv, codecs
import sqlite3

# Encoding fix
def latin_1_encoder(unicode_csv_data):
    for line in unicode_csv_data:
        yield line.encode('latin-1')

fileName = 'australianpublicholidays.csv'
accessMode = 'r'

# Create a database in RAM
holidayDatabase = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

# Create a cursor
c = holidayDatabase.cursor()

# Create a table
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE holidays 
(date text, holidayName text, information text, moreInformation text, applicableTo text)''')

# Read the file contents in to the table
# Encoding fix
with codecs.open(fileName, accessMode, encoding='latin-1') as publicHolidays :
    listOfPublicHolidays = csv.reader(latin_1_encoder(publicHolidays))
    # Skip the header row
    next(listOfPublicHolidays, None)
    entries = []
    for currentRow in listOfPublicHolidays:
        # Work-around for "You must not use 8-bit bytestrings" error
        entries.append(tuple([unicode(field, 'latin-1') for field in currentRow]))
    c.executemany('INSERT INTO holidays VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', entries)

# Close the database
holidayDatabase.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected the error by removing the nested for loop

> Replaced the following

```
# Read the file contents in to the table
with open(fileName, accessMode) as publicHolidays :
    listOfPublicHolidays = csv.reader(publicHolidays)

    for currentRow in listOfPublicHolidays :
        for currentEntry in currentRow :
            c.execute('INSERT INTO holidays VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', currentEntry)
```

> With the following

```
with open(fileName, accessMode) as publicHolidays :
    listOfPublicHolidays = csv.reader(publicHolidays)

    for currentRow in listOfPublicHolidays :
            c.execute('INSERT INTO holidays VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', currentRow)
```

However the cause of the error is still unclear to me.